# When printing arrays with variables, it prints individual answers, not all

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

This is a program to save the age and the last name of a person:

```
E = Array.new(10)
A = Array.new(10)
for i in(0..9)
  puts "¿Cúal es tu edad?"
  edad = gets.chomp
  E[i] = edad
  puts "¿Cúal es tu apellido?"
  apellido = gets.chomp
  A[i] = apellido
end
 gets
for m in(0..9)
  puts "Apellido es " + A.to_s + " tengo " + E.to_s + " años. "
end
gets
```

It prints:

```
Apellido es ["primero", "segundo", "tercero", "cuarto", "quinto", "sexto", "septimo", "octavo", "noveno", "decimo"] tengo ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"] años.
Apellido es ["primero", "segundo", "tercero", "cuarto", "quinto", "sexto", "septimo", "octavo", "noveno", "decimo"] tengo ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"] años.
Apellido es ["primero", "segundo", "tercero", "cuarto", "quinto", "sexto", "septimo", "octavo", "noveno", "decimo"] tengo ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"] años.
Apellido es ["primero", "segundo", "tercero", "cuarto", "quinto", "sexto", "septimo", "octavo", "noveno", "decimo"] tengo ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"] años.
Apellido es ["primero", "segundo", "tercero", "cuarto", "quinto", "sexto", "septimo", "octavo", "noveno", "decimo"] tengo ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"] años.
Apellido es ["primero", "segundo", "tercero", "cuarto", "quinto", "sexto", "septimo", "octavo", "noveno", "decimo"] tengo ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"] años.
Apellido es ["primero", "segundo", "tercero", "cuarto", "quinto", "sexto", "septimo", "octavo", "noveno", "decimo"] tengo ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"] años.
Apellido es ["primero", "segundo", "tercero", "cuarto", "quinto", "sexto", "septimo", "octavo", "noveno", "decimo"] tengo ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"] años.
Apellido es ["primero", "segundo", "tercero", "cuarto", "quinto", "sexto", "septimo", "octavo", "noveno", "decimo"] tengo ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"] años.
Apellido es ["primero", "segundo", "tercero", "cuarto", "quinto", "sexto", "septimo", "octavo", "noveno", "decimo"] tengo ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"] años.
```

When I introduce 10 and 10 variables, and print them, it prints all information, not 1 and 1. It makes all of them at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change one of you line to, so you can access array elements by index (but don't use capitals for variable names):

```
puts "Apellido es " + A[m].to_s + " tengo " + E[m].to_s + " años. "
```

But I suggest to make your code more "Rubyish", like so:

```
people = Array.new() # initializa an array
10.times do |n|
  person = {} # initialize a hash
  # puts "¿Cúal es tu edad?"
  person[:edad] = 20 + n # stores into the hash, here use gets for user input instead of 20 + n
  # puts "¿Cúal es tu apellido?"
  person[:apellido] = 'Pedro' + n.to_s # stores into the hash, here use gets for user input instead of 'Pedro' + n.to_s
  people << person # insert the person into people
end
people.each do |person|
  puts "Apellido es #{person[:apellido]} tengo #{person[:edad]} años." # string interpolation
end
```

- Looping by `.times do`: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Integer.html#method-i-times
- Storing people data using hashes: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html
- Iterating over array by: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-each
- Using string interpolation: https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.5.0/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Strings